# BeautifulSoup getting value from chart style

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the value from the `red` and `green` bar chart in this table from [here](https://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=5259.MY) :
[image]

As you can see in `Inspect Element`, they are handling a data and represent as a graph.
Right now, I'm struggling to get value and always having an empty array as the result (named them as `empty1` and `empty2`).

Here is my coding :

```
shareInvestorRequest = requests.get(str('https://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=5259.MY'), headers=header)
shareInvestorParser = BeautifulSoup(shareInvestorRequest.text, 'html.parser')

try:
    totalShareholderReturnTable = shareInvestorParser.find('tbody', {'id':'factSheet_totalReturn'}).findAll('tr')
    totalShareholderReturnSelectedRow = []
    
    for totalShareholderReturnRow in totalShareholderReturnTable[1:]:
        navigatedtotalShareholderReturnColumn = [td.text.strip() for td in totalShareholderReturnRow.findAll("td")]
        
        totalShareholderReturnSelectedRow.append(navigatedtotalShareholderReturnColumn)
        totalShareholderReturnLimitedTable = pd.DataFrame(totalShareholderReturnSelectedRow,
                                                          columns=['Period', 'Dividend Received', 'Capital Appreciation', '', '', 'Total Shareholder Return'])
    
    i = 0
    for totalShareholderReturnRow in totalShareholderReturnTable[1:]:
        i += 1
        selectedColumn = [td.text.strip() for td in totalShareholderReturnRow.findAll("td")]
        dividendReceived = selectedColumn[1]
        capitalAppreciation = selectedColumn[2]
        empty1 = selectedColumn[3]
        empty2 = selectedColumn[4]
        totalSReturn = selectedColumn[5]

    print(str(selectedColumn) + ' ' + str(dividendReceived) + ' ' + str(capitalAppreciation) + str(empty1) + str(empty2) + ' ' + str(totalSReturn))


print("")
    print("============================== TOTAL SHAREHOLDER RETURN ==============================\n")
    
    print(totalShareholderReturnLimitedTable)

    print("======================================================================================\n")
```

Having them as the result:

[image]

Can you please help?
Thanks!

Comment: But you have the values ready in the last column and you do extract them. Why extract also the chart values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the html source you will notice there is `style` attribute of `div` tag inside respective `td` tag. The value is something like `width: 8.3%`. Width value is alwas positive, so I add sign based on value in last column.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://www.shareinvestor.com/fundamental/factsheet.html?counter=5259.MY')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')


TSR_table = soup.find('div', {'id':'sic_factsheet_totalReturn'}).find('table', {"class":"sic_table sic_tableBigCell"})
table_body = TSR_table.find('tbody')
data = []
for tr in table_body.find_all('tr'):
    row = []
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        field = td.string
        if not field:
            div = td.find('div')
            if div:
                field = div.get('style')[7:]
        if field:
            row.append(field)
    if row:
        row[-2] = f'{row[-1][0]}{row[-2]}'
        data.append(row)
print(data)
```

output

```
[['5 Days', '-', '+0.010', '+8.3%', '+8.33 %'],
 ['10 Days', '-', '+0.025', '+23.8%', '+23.81 %'],
 ['20 Days', '-', '+0.045', '+52.9%', '+52.94 %'],
 ['3 Months', '-', '+0.020', '+18.2%', '+18.18 %'],
 ['6 Months', '-', '-0.075', '-36.6%', '-36.59 %'],
 ['1 Year', '-', '-0.195', '-60.0%', '-60.00 %'],
 ['2 Years', '-', '-0.280', '-68.3%', '-68.29 %'],
 ['3 Years', '-', '-0.275', '-67.9%', '-67.90 %'],
 ['5 Years', '-', '-0.630', '-82.9%', '-82.89 %'],
 ['Annualised', '-', '-', '-29.8%', '-29.75 %']]
```